# How to include a list in a raw_input? Closed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that there are many questions similar to this but they don't answer my question. I want to know how to include a list in a raw_input. I have my code:

```
Choices = ['random_one', 'random_two']
Choice = raw_input("The choices are:" + "and ".join(Choices) + ": ")
```

This code works but I have a problem. It prints like this:

```
The choices are and :
```

I want it to print like this:

`The choices are random_one and random_2`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That statement `var = raw_input("Text" str(List_Name))` is not proper Python syntax and it will *not* work. Please show your actual code and explain just what text you typed for the `input` statement.

Comment: @RoryDaulton When I run it, it runs it properly, it doesn't say `syntax Error`.

Comment: Then you aren't running the code you've posted.

Comment: @RoryDaulton @chepner Oops, I forgot to put in `+` in the code. Let me just edit the question and you can get back to this in 5 minutes.

Comment: @12944qwerty - When you get a chance, please read [ask] and especially [mcve]. One advice from those pages is to always copy-paste your example code, never retype or summarize it.

Comment: Also, what does the title of this question have to do with the question itself? I don't see anything in the question about clearing screens. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Robᵩ I actually forgot to change it because it was from a question I was making before but then found out somewhere else. I have changed it now.

Comment: @Robᵩ - I will read it sometime and thank your for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method would come in handy for this:

```
Choice_1 = raw_input("The choices are: " + ", ".join(Choices) + ": ")
```

Result:

```
The choices are: random1, random2, random3:
```

Comment: Very well. That's the beauty of `str.join()`. It takes an arbitrary number of items: 0, 1, 2, or more. In the case where `len(Choices)==2`, it might look like this: `The choices are: random1, random2: `

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I think the easiest way to do this is just

```
Choice_1 = raw_input("The choices are: " + (", ".join(Choices)))
```

What this does is join each item in the list with `", "`. The parentheses are necessary because otherwise it would read `", "` first instead.

Comment: Just to let you know yours is the exact same as the one I accepted

Answer (score 0):

you can format a string however you like:

```
formatted_list = '{}, {}, {}'.format(var[0], var[1], var[2])
print(format)
```

If you dont know how long the list is just put it in a for loop or even better strip the string list:

```
print(var.strip('[').strip(']').strip("'"))
```

Comment: I do know how many their are 'cause I created the list. Just letting you know.

Comment: Using [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is easier.

Comment: @GreenMatt - Would you know how to the `.join` for only 2 variables?

Comment: @12944qwerty: joins are done on lists. If you have 2 string variables, s1 and s2, you could create a list containing them and join them with: `', '.join([s1, s2])`

Comment: @GreenMatt -  What if they are variables? Then how would it work? Would you have to do a similar code: `', '.join([var1, var2])`

Comment: @12944qwerty: I already answered how you would handle it if they are string variables; if they are scalar, but not string, variables, you can use the [str()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=built%20function#str) function. That said, this is turning into more than can be handled via comments. Search for (a) question(s) that address(es) your issue(s) and check out the answers there; in the (unlikely, I expect) event that such a question doesn't exist, ask a new one.

Comment: @GreenMatt `str.join` only takes one argument. Is there a way to fix that? BTW I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: @12944qwerty: I've already answered that above, please review those comments; and I've been referring you to 2.7 documentation. As I inferred in my last comment, this is not the way to seek help on this site, look for other ***questions*** that might help. Please don't ask me more questions via this comment thread; I won't answer.